# trying to get Apache 2.4 to conditionally server .webp via mod_rewrite, need another view

Tags: apache, webp

I have Apache 2.2.15 configured on the test bed server to serve .webp in lieu of .jpg and .png if available.  This works successfully.  However, the same configuration does not seem to work on the outward-facing server running Apache 2.4.51.

These are the applicable lines from /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
    ...
    AddType image/webp .webp
    ...
    </IfModule>

<IfModule  rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Edg    [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.webp -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(?:jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [NC,T=image/webp,E=webp,L]
<IfModule headers_module>
    <FilesMatch "(?i)\.(jpe?g|png)$">
        Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_webp
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

The only difference between the two configuration files is a) use of the module names (so as to be consistent with the rest of the configuration files) versus the source-file name, and b) the AddType for image/webp is inside the IfModule mime_module block.

I have checked ( httpd -M ) that mod_mime, mod_rewrite and mod_headers.so are all loaded so that isn't the issue (?). Tested with both Chrome and Edge as clients.  Verified that the webp images did get there with release make via find(1). but...

Environmentally, the inward facing test bed serves via http, the outward facing production serves via https, but for the life of me I dont know how that would have any affect???

Anyway, I would appreciate a new set of eyeballs on this. [On the test bed, this knocked off about 40% of the page load, so its a rather  big deal .]